# include hg subrepository in projectile

Tags: projectile, mercurial

I am using projectile in a project with many externals (hg subrepositories). Each subrepository is treated as a separate project by Projectile. Is there any way to configure Projectile to automatically include subrepos to the main project? Or can/must this be done manually?

Comment: Does projectile behave the same way with Git (submodules)? Is each submodule treated as a separate project?